# Finding recurrence relation from an exponential generating function

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, ordinary-differential-equations

Problem: Let $d_n$ be the number of derangements of $[n]$. Let $D(x) = \sum\limits_{n\geq 0} d_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$ be the exponential generating function of $\{d_n\}$. Find $D(x)$ to determine the recurrence relation for $d_n$.

---

I am almost done solving this problem. Rearranging and shifting some terms, I got the separable ODE
$$\cfrac{D'(x)}{D(x)} = \cfrac{x}{1-x}$$
Integrating both sides and solving for $D(x)$, I got
$$D(x) = \cfrac{e^{-x}}{1-x}$$
Now I am just stuck on using the result for $D$ to get $d_n$. Using the sum and product rules, I understand that $d_n = (n-1)(d_{n-1}+d_{n-2})$, but I've not had any luck getting this result from $D(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use binomial convolution.  If $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are exponential generating functions with terms $\{a_n\}_{n \ge 0}$ and $\{b_n\}_{n \ge 0}$, then $D(x) = A(x)B(x)$ has the EGF with
$$d_n = \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} a_m b_{n-m}. \tag{1}$$
The proof is straightforward and is left as an exercise.  Consequently, with the choice $A(x) = e^{-x}$ and $B(x) = (1-x)^{-1}$, we have
$$a_n = (-1)^n, \quad b_n = n!,$$ hence
$$d_n = \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} (-1)^m (n-m)! = \sum_{m=0}^n (-1)^m \frac{n!}{m!}. \tag{2}$$
All that remains is to show that $(2)$ satisfies the recursion $$d_n = (n-1)(d_{n-1} + d_{n-2}). \tag{3}$$  This is also straightforward and left as an exercise.